# Remove all nfs4_setfacl entries

Tags: linux, acl

I've been testing with nfs4_setfacl and as a result I have hundreds of entries on some directories.  It has now gotten to the point where I can't even view the list and it errors out:

```
[root@server max_data]# nfs4_getfacl /path/to/data/support/MAX/max_data/1999/
Failed getxattr operation: Numerical result out of range
```

Is there a way to mass delete all ACLs from this directory? The only thing I've been able to find you have to be able to specify the entry that you want to remove - but seeing as how I can't even view them I can't do that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the –s option alone makes it have just the single entry you have entered:

```
[root@server files]# nfs4_getfacl test_several_acl2
Failed getxattr operation: Numerical result out of range

[root@server max_data]# nfs4_setfacl -s A::bob123:rwx 1999

[root@server max_data]# nfs4_getfacl 1999
A::bob123@DOMAIN:rwx
```